# MySQL: отнять значение из каждого столбца пропорционально его весу

Tags: mysql, sql

Из каждого значения столбца нужно пропорционально отнять часть определенной суммы. В столбце куча строк с целыми числами числами

```
1 200000
2 400000
3 100000
```

Необходимо из общей суммы 700 000 отнять 235 000.

Сделал так, но отнимает не равномерно, не пропорционально значению столбца

```
UPDATE Таблица SET Сумма = Сумма - 2000;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql

Comment: Вопрос абсолютно не ясен, приведите образец исходных данных и что должно получится на выходе.

Comment: таблица : Оплата

калонки : Сумма1, Сумма2, тип оплаты.
в колонках сумма1 и сумма2 (числовые значения),тип оплаты( оплата или неоплата)- ( текстовое значение).
 Необходим скрипт который выполняет следующее: 
заполнить столбец  Сумма1 рандомными сумами в определенном диапазоне например я вбиваю 2 000 000 и эта сума делится на все строки причем редактируется только вид оплаты (оплата). И Колонка: сумма1 и сумма2 должны иметь одинаковые значения.

Comment: совсем ничего не понятно

Comment: Столбец(Сумма)
100000
200000
300000
500000
800000
Строк в столбце очень много.

Необходимо: есть значение которое непостоянное, я в скрипт вбиваю это значение допустим 300 000 и это значение вычитается из всего столбца.
должно получится примерно так 300000/количество строк (5 в данном случае) и вычитается с каждой строки.
100000 - 60000=40000
200000 - 60000=140000
300000 - 60000=240000
500000- 60000 =440000
800000- 60000= 740000
но значение строки должно быть больше 0.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала вычисли вклад `weight` каждой из записей в общую сумму по всей таблице

```
SELECT
  price,
  price / ( SELECT SUM(price) FROM balans) AS weight
FROM
  balans
```

Именно тот вес нужно умножить на вычитаемое число 235 000, чтобы оно равномерно распределилось между всеми записями таблицы

```
SELECT
  price,
  235000 * (price / ( SELECT SUM(price) FROM balans)) AS diff
FROM
  balans
```

Теперь остается только вычесть это значение в операторе `UPDATE`. Однако, обычный UPDATE-запрос не сработает

```
UPDATE
  balans
SET
  price = price - 235000 * (price / ( SELECT SUM(price) FROM balans));
```

> Не допускается указание таблицы 'balans' в списке таблиц FROM для
>   внесения в нее изменений

Придется составить многотабличный запрос. Сначала составим многотабличный запрос с суммой и значением, которое из этой суммы необходимо вычесть

```
SELECT
  balans.price AS original,
  235000 * bcount.price / total.summ AS result
FROM
    balans
  JOIN
    balans AS bcount
  ON
    balans.id = bcount.id
  JOIN
    (SELECT SUM(price) AS summ FROM balans) AS total
```

Теперь не трудно составить UPDATE-запрос

```
UPDATE
    balans
  JOIN
    balans AS bcount
  ON
    balans.id = bcount.id
  JOIN
    (SELECT SUM(price) AS summ FROM balans) AS total
SET
  balans.price = bcount.price - 235000 * bcount.price / total.summ
```

Теперь, если посчитать сумму столбцов, вместо 700 000 получается 465 000, как раз за вычетом 235 000

```
SELECT SUM(price) FROM balans
```